# How to get movies by date

Tags: php, timestamp

Ola,

i am building a complex cinema site, and i want to get movies by date

Ex: The movies are aded trought post type,

I have a custom field name date.

How can i retrive the Movie that shoud play today in cinema ( date in custom field : 08.09.2012...)

Ex: How can i retrive the movie by date

Site: http://cinema.trancelevel.com/cinema/in-curand/

Movies that apear today...in righit

Like This?
`

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key' => 'premiera_cinema',
    'meta_value' => date('Y-m-d'),
    'meta_compare' => '='
);
$todays_movies = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php while ($todays_movies->have_posts()) : $todays_movies->the_post(); ?>
<div class="sidebar-titlu"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
<div class="sidebar-stiri">
<img src="/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php the_field('img'); ?>&h=60&w=90&zc=1" alt="" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
<?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();echo string_limit_words($excerpt,30);?><a class="detalii" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('Permanent Link to %s', 'kubrick'), the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>">...detalii</a>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: tomorrow i want to get the movies that play tomorrow, i want to get the post automate by live date, and if there is no movie i want to display a message , no movie this day

Comment: have you researched something like: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/custom-loop-based-on-custom-fields/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to query on your dates beyond a simple date comparison you should reverse the format of your date field. Dates should always follow the [MySQL date format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) for reliable querying and sorting: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

To query movies for today you would use a [meta query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters):

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'post_type' => 'movie',
    'meta_key' => '_date_key',
    'meta_value' => date('Y-m-d'),
    'meta_compare' => '='
);

$todays_movies = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to dynamically get todays data formatted the same as what you store in the custom field like this:

```
$today = date('m.d.Y');
```

Then make a new query that gets one movie with a custom field called "date" that has the value of $today, like this:

```
$q = new WP_Query('post_type=movies&posts_per_page=1&meta_key=date&meta_value='.$today);
```

Then run a loop with that query. Every day the $today variable will change, and so will the movie returned. NOTE: you may have to define your timezone before using the date() function so the $today variable is updated at midnight your time. Set your timezone using this function: `date_default_timezone_set()`

Here is a list of supported timezones you can enter as the parameter for the above function:
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Query strings are called "deprecated" these days. They work, but you shouldn't use them anymore.